# WordPress post text corruption

Tags: php, windows, wordpress, apache

Yesterday I began a small private blog using WordPress 4.1 (Windows 7, Apache 2.4, MySQL 5.5, PHP 5.6.1, UTF8, generally common settings). I started to transfer my articles into it; several of them was fine, but I found two articles which cannot be saved correctly.

When trying to save these articles as posts WordPress refreshes and shows corrupted version of text. Exact corruption is: middle of the article is removed while several garbage characters (%D? for example) inserted instead of it.

I tried to update WP to the current (4.2.2) version - error is the same (upd.: 4.2.3 - error is the same). I tried to save article as the page instead of post - error is the same. I tried the standard theme instead of custom - error is the same.

It looks like 'issued' articles are longer than others - 5.2Kb and 7.5Kb. I tried to see what happens if I would save lesser pieces. While saving a very short piece it works fine. If make a longer piece, WP losts tail of this text. If make a more longer piece, WP starts to lose the middle as described above.

Currently I have no idea how to repair or debug this case. Any suggestions?

========== Additional info ==========

I tried to execute this code into my blog:

```
<?php

  $my_post = array(
     'post_title' => 'Caption',
     'post_status' => 'publish',
     'post_content' => 'the very-very-long text of my article'
  );

  echo wp_insert_post( $my_post );

?>
```

When executed, it makes excellent post as it should be (thanks to urka_mazurka for advicing this).

When I tried to edit this post into WP, it becames corrupted when saving too. Moreover, when I tried to edit this PHP file into WP (using editing theme facility), it becomes corrupted when saving too.

===== Additional info 2 =====

Table `wp_posts` collation is `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` (result of SHOW TABLE STATUS)

It looks like urka_mazurka were the closest... at least I can publish these posts via `wp_insert_post`. Too bad I can't address bounty to him because he didn't publish any answer.

Comment: Can you please show sample content which is getting trimmed ?

Comment: For example, the text of http://www.proza.ru/2014/11/15/241. Screenshot before saving can be viewed at http://s017.radikal.ru/i420/1507/a0/f3c95ececa4b.png . Screenshot after save is http://s017.radikal.ru/i411/1507/15/2b9f5d840d0f.png

Comment: Screenshot of http://s020.radikal.ru/i703/1507/04/e757755f3e52.png is more suitable. Red line shows corrupted characters which replaces several paragraphs of original text.

Comment: You mentioned you changed themes - but never talked about any installed plugins or disabling them.  Do you have any?

Comment: No, at the moment I have no any plugin.

Comment: Just a wild guess - what is yours Database schema? Check for ```wp_posts``` table column lengths, may be it's truncated there?

Comment: You said "I started to transfer my articles into it" that is the whole problem. How are you doing this? Transferring from where, to what?

Comment: Jim, you can see second comment for example. I had transferred from miscellaneous html/text sources via copy-paste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I've solved it.

All this #@$@#$@#$ was because of misspelling into php.ini's sys_temp_dir option. Every time when PHP engine fails to make a temporary file, post contents had been squeezed using this unique technique without any visible warning.

Answer (score 1):

according to your explanation the problem seems to be with the WordPress core, I'll recommend you to try a different approach:

1. Insert a post using **wp_insert_post** function but without content or a "safe" content like one simple word.
2. Then use [$wpdb](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#UPDATE_rows) to update the post with the real content.

Here is a snipped of how I'll do it:

```
  $my_post = array(
     'post_title' => 'Caption',
     'post_status' => 'publish',
     'post_content' => 'dummy text'
  );
//get the post id
  $post_id = wp_insert_post( $my_post );

global $wpdb;
//now update the post with the real text
$wpdb->update( 
     $wpdb->prefix . 'posts', 
    array( 
        'post_content' => 'YOUR LONG TEXT HERE',    
    ), 
    array( 'ID' => $post_id ), 
    array('%s'), 
    array('%d') 
);
```

If you don't get the result you want with this, then is a problem with your php config or MySQL configuration unless you are willing to try a more unfriendly solution and use [$wpdb->query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Running_General_Queries) instead of `$wpdb->update` like this:

```
$big_text = "YOUR BIG TEXT HERE";
$wpdb->query(
    "UPDATE $wpdb->posts 
    SET post_content = $big_text
    WHERE ID = $post_id"
);
```

Let us know.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the articles you are transferring over have no embedded character encoding. This is a common problem when you try to copy over stuff from a formatted document like a Microsoft Word doc, since it saves character encoding information when the text is copied.

In the WordPress WYSIWYG box, there is an icon to reveal source code. You might be able to spot strange character encoding by viewing this.

Else, try pasting your articles in a text editor and converting all the text to standard UTF-8 encoding before pasting into WordPress.

Comment: Thank you. I guess there are no any embedded characters (I don't use WordPress's wysiwyg among other matters). I tried to paste into WordPress from Notepad++ UTF-8 text, nothing changes.

Comment: what if you try to insert post content via an ajax function (calling wp_insert_post) ? in this way, you should be able to exclude database problems

Comment: Thanks, @urka_mazurka, I tried this (described as addition in the question text)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to disable mod_security ([through .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30206732/3402095))?

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>
```

There are a lot of people complaining about problems related to saving long posts in Wordpress, or posts which can't be saved because of certain words. That's because sometimes Wordpress won't play nicely with `mod_security` enabled. Some of them solved this by disabling this feature...Some of them solved this by changing WP memory limit... Maybe some of these will help you to solve your problem (or at least to narrow it down).

Comment: Thanks for answer. I tried this - nothing changed :( Exactly, I put these lines into the blog's .htaccess after #END WORDPRESS, restarted Apache, tried to save text and looked corruption as usual.

Comment: I believe these rules need to come *before* WordPress's rules.

Answer (score 0):

A Couple of Suggestions:

*Never Copy / Paste from Word to WordPress.

*Always make sure to past in un-formatted clean text

*If your not sure, you can always copy / paste into notepad ++, then copy / paste into wordpress.

*If your seeing weird characters, that could be a UTF8 encoding issue. We used to have that issue when bubbling up the site from Dev Environment to Integration Environment. We solved it by opening the .sql whole database in notepad++, and going to Encoding -> UTF8 -> Save

Answer (score 0):

You need to check "wp-config.php" file to confirm the code written below is present in it:

```
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
```

If the above code is present in the file and you still getting the issue then add [this code](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/utf-8-encoding-problem) in theme's 'header.php' file.

Comment: Thanks, but nothing changes

Answer (score 0):

Add **Post Author** and **Post Type** for your post

In here pass user id as post_author ( 1 is the first user that we create on wordpress installation)

```
$my_post = array(
    'post_title' => 'Caption',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_type'   => 'post',
    'post_content' => 'the very-very-long text of my article',
    'post_author'   => 1,
);
```